# How to install an android application in a Nook (Not Nook Color) + without rooting

Tags: android, nook

I have a requirement to start up the browser of an E-Ink Nook and point it to a specific URL. Since the Nook runs on Android 1.5, the most obvious solution to this was to write an Android app that listens to the boot event and starts up as the browser once the OS starts up.

After writing the application and testing on standard android emulators, I just couldn't find a way to install it on the device. Most suggestions say that rooting the device is a solution, but this is not an option in my case.

I have almost come to the conclusion that it will not be possible without rooting the device.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could prove me wrong or at confirm that it can't be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: im not sure this is the right venue for this question since this isn't really a programming question. in any case, i am fairly certain that you are right, it is not possible without root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to root the device.  You need to sign up as a Nook developer and then you can get a provision.cmd file that you put on the device, which allows you to install and debug apps on it.

Here's a thread I was just involved in, you'll need to be logged in with a developer account:

https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/21458241

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the search option on a nook and enter there an URL, so the main screen transforms into a web browser.